# R: remove row if certain value can be found in other row

Tags: r, conditional-statements, row, subset

I work with a dataset where I want to remove a row if the tag is 1 and there is an id number where the tag is 3. EDIT: tags value can only be: NA, 1, 2 or 3. id numbers are distinct and are only find three times if there exists a tag 1, tag 2 and tag 3.

`> dat1 = data.frame(id=c(15399,15404,15405,15407,15407,15407,15403), tag=c(NA,NA,1,1,2,3,1))`

`> dat1
     id tag
1 15399  NA
2 15404  NA
3 15405   1
4 15407   1
5 15407   2
6 15407   3
7 15403   1`

I need to return this:

`> dat1
     id tag
1 15399  NA
2 15404  NA
3 15405   1
5 15407   2
6 15407   3
7 15403   1`

Could someone help me? I only figured out how to remove all the ID's where the tag is 3:

`> subset(dat1,!dat1$id %in% dat1$id[dat1$tag == 3])
     id tag
1 15399  NA
2 15404  NA
3 15405   1
7 15403   1`

Comment: `dat2 <- dat1[dat1$tag!="1",]` why not something like this? (for this to work you have to avoid/change NA values)

Comment: Are trying to remove duplicate rows from the dataframe?

Comment: @jyr That will also remove row 3 which I want to keep. I only want to remove a row containing tag 1 if there exist a row with the same id number with the tag 3.

Comment: @BidishaPyne in a certain way yes: if there is id which has tag 1 and an other one with tag 3, I'm only interessed in keeping tag 3 with that id number.

Comment: You want to keep the tag with only bigger tag numbers?

Comment: @AlihanZıhna I want to keep NA, 1 (if there is no other tag number with the same ID number as tag 1). Tag 2 and tag 3 (both with the same ID number) I want to keep if there is a tag 1 under that same ID number. But then that tag 1 needs to be removed. See also edited explanation about the range of values of tag and id.

Comment: @akrun thank you for noticing. I will edited the post.

Comment: @Mylene A doubt, you removed the row containing 15405 where tag is 1 while kept the row with id 15403 and tag 1 in the expected.  I am confused now

Comment: @akrun in data1 I need to remove row 4 containg id 15407 and tag 1. I'm sorry for the confusion, but the row containing id 15405 needs to stay. The post is now correctly edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat1[!duplicated(dat1$id,fromLast = TRUE)|duplicated(dat1$id)&dat1$tag!="1",]
```

You can do it simply like this but first you need to order data by tag. Its not very pretty way but it should work.

```
> dat1[!duplicated(dat1$id,fromLast = TRUE)|duplicated(dat1$id)&dat1$tag!="1",]
     id tag
1 15399  NA
2 15404  NA
3 15405   1
5 15407   2
6 15407   3
7 15403   1
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. What do yo mean that I need to order the data by tag? Because it seems to works just fine in with dat1, which is not order by tag. Or does the function `duplicated` already does that?

Comment: `duplicated()` goes throught the vector and returns TRUE/FALSE whenever the element already apeard in the vector. So `duplicated(c(1,1,2,3,2))` will return FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE. with parametr `fromLast=TRUE` it will start at the end and it will return TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE.

edit: the filter says everything that is not duplicated and everything that is but doesnt have tag 1. Its order sensitive and it might have problems if you have duplicates only with tag 1.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat1)[, .SD[any(tag != 1) & tag !=1 | all(tag==1) |is.na(tag)] , by = id]
#      id tag
#1: 15399  NA
#2: 15404  NA
#3: 15405   1
#4: 15407   2
#5: 15407   3
#6: 15403   1
```

If the condition is to delete the row that have 'tag' as 1 where there is also a 'tag' 3 for a particular 'id', then

```
setDT(dat1)[, .SD[!(all(c(1,3) %in% tag) & tag == 1)]  , id]
#      id tag
#1: 15399  NA
#2: 15404  NA
#3: 15405   1
#4: 15407   2
#5: 15407   3
#6: 15403   1
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(any(tag != 1) & tag !=1 | all(tag==1) |is.na(tag))
```

Based on the second condition

```
dat1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(!(all(c(1,3) %in% tag) & tag ==1))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups: id [5]
#     id   tag
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 15399    NA
#2 15404    NA
#3 15405     1
#4 15407     2
#5 15407     3
#6 15403     1
```

Comment: This only removed row 3 in dat1, but I want to remove row 4 (which shared the same ID as tag 3 on row 6)

Answer (score 0):

```
 dat1 = data.frame(id=c(15399,15404,15405,15407,15407,15407,15403), 
 tag=c(NA,NA,1,1,2,3,1))#construct the data
 dat1_tag3<-dat1[dat1$tag==3,]#keep the rows with tag equals to 3
 dat1_tag3<-dat1_tag3[!is.na(dat1_tag3$id),]#remove NA's
 dat2remove<-dat1[(dat1$id %in% unique(dat1_tag3$id) & dat1$tag==1),]#find rows that need to be excluded

 all<-rbind(dat1,dat2remove)#rbinding the two datasets
 all<-all[!(duplicated(all[c("id","tag")]) | duplicated(all[c("id","tag")], fromLast = TRUE)),]#removing duplicates (as pairs)

    id tag
1 15399  NA
2 15404  NA
3 15405   1
5 15407   2
6 15407   3
7 15403   1
```

Comment: upload if you like. Merci